# nginx rewrite both .php and .html

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Have 2 rules for working files with (html, php) prefix and without.

But working only first rule. If first php, second with html prefix show not found.

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/([^\.]+)$ /$1.php break;
}

if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/([^\.]+)$ /$1.html break;
}
```

If I swap them working with html. How merge to working both. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to reinvent [`try_files`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) with these `if` conditions?

In that case, this should work:

```
try_files $uri $uri.php $uri.html;
```

Comment: This return 404. I try popular rules:  

if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html(\?|$)) {

        return 302 /$1;

    }

    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;


It not working